# Android sqlite Crosstab

Tags: java, android, sqlite

What better alternative to produce a crosstab in Sqlite via Android/java?

**I have:**

```
[TABLE people]
<i>_id, NAME
1, "mary"
2, "juan"
3, "jose"</i>

[TABLE GLASSES]
_id, COLOR
1, "BLACK"
2, "BLUE"
3, "GRAY"
4, "YELLOW"
...

[TABLE PEOPLE_GLASSES]
_id, idpeople, idglass, qty
1, 1, 1, 50
2, 1, 3, 30
3, 1, 4, 25
...
```

**I need:**

```
[crosstab]
NAME   | BLACK | GRAY | YELLOW
"mary" | 50    | 30   | 25
...
```

how to do this?

Comment: Clear the intent of your question...

Comment: What you want exactly..??? I think you want to use joining the table, is it...????

Comment: No. joins not convert rows into columns

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have any built-in function to convert rows into columns.

You have to read the `GLASSES` table first, and then, based on that data, dynamically create another query like this:

```sql
SELECT NAME,
       (SELECT qty
        FROM PEOPLE_GLASSES
        WHERE idpeople = people._id
          AND idglass = 1
       ) AS "BLACK",
       (SELECT qty
        FROM PEOPLE_GLASSES
        WHERE idpeople = people._id
          AND idglass = 2
       ) AS "BLUE",
       (SELECT qty
        FROM PEOPLE_GLASSES
        WHERE idpeople = people._id
          AND idglass = 3
       ) AS "GRAY",
       (SELECT qty
        FROM PEOPLE_GLASSES
        WHERE idpeople = people._id
          AND idglass = 4
       ) AS "YELLOW"
FROM people
```

Comment: It is not very efficient. If my tables grow?

Comment: How would you imlpement this more efficiently?